# How to use Image conrtrol in asp.net (C# web)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an image stored in my MS Access database with the data type OLE Object. I want it to display in an `Image` control. How can I do this? I tried this, but only in a `PictureBox` control in windows forms. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a page that can read the image from the database as binary data, then write that data directly to http response as binary data using Response.BinaryWrite to feed the image out. Then the src attribute of your image is pointed at the page itself like:

```
<img src="image.aspx" />
```

And the code behind image.aspx:

```
// An assumed method to get binary data our of the database  
var bytes = YourDataLayer.GetBinaryImageData();  

Response.Clear();   
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=filename.jpg");   
Response.ContentType = @"image\jpg";   
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);   
Response.End();
```

Answer (score -1):

read the image from the database as byte array and then create a temperary image object and assign it to the webcontrol on the page